# How to collecting yii tabular input form?

Tags: php, forms, yii, tabular

I made yii tabular input form, but every i submit this form its data can't save to database.

it  is my view:

```
<div class="row" id="email_usul0" style="display:none;">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modeljenis, 'email_usulan'); //email usulan jika yang dipilih bagian ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modeljenis, "email_usulan[0]", array('style' => 'width: 330px;')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modeljenis, 'email_usulan'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row" id="nipnip0" style="display:none;">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modeljenis, 'nip_baru'); //email usulan jika yang dipilih pegawai (tidak autocomplete, diisi eselon 3 ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modeljenis, "nip_baru[0]", array('style' => 'width: 330px;')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modeljenis, 'nip_baru'); ?>
</div>
```

It is my controller for save post data:

```
public function actionEmail() {

    $model = new EmailForm();
    $modeljenis = array();
    $modeljenis = new JenisEmailForm();

    if (isset($_POST['EmailForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['EmailForm'];
        $model->memo = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'memo');

        if ($model->validate()) {

            $email = new Email;

            $email->nama = 'NAME';
            $email->email_kirim = $model->email_kirim;
            $model->memo->saveAs($path);

            foreach($_POST['JenisEmailForm'] as $i=>$modele)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['JenisEmailForm'][$i])){

                        $modeljenis[$i]->attributes=$modele;

                        $email->jenis_email = $modeljenis[$i]->jenis_email;
                        $email->save();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->render('email', array('model' => $model,'modeljenis' => $modeljenis, ));

}
```

It can't save data to the mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you declare your $path variable?

Comment: this is my $path variable:  $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/images/' . $model->memo;
    $model->memo->saveAs($path);